# ng-file-upload v12.0.1 - Displaying a temporary 'loading' icon while thumbnail is being generated

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-file-upload

Our app allows users to select multiple large images for upload.

Using the '**ngf-thumbnail**' directive can sometimes be slow in generating the previews.

Is there a nice way to display a loading icon (or any other image) while the thumbnails are being processed?

```
 <img ngf-thumbnail="file" ngf-size="{width: 100, height: 100, quality: 0.5}"/>
```

Comment: use `  ngf-before-model-change="beforeChange($files, ...)" // called after file select/drop and before ...` to detect the file selection and then show the loading icon and remove it once the src of the img is set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by doing the following:

```
<img ng-src="/spinner.gif" ngf-thumbnail="file" ngf-size="{width: 100, height: 100, quality: 0.5}"/>
```

When ng-file-upload is done generating the thumbnail, it effectively replaces the original 'src' set by ng-src.